# CS:GO rank gone

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I've been playing quite a lot of competitive games of CS:GO and after Christmas holidays my rank has disappeared, since I didn't play at all during holidays. On Steam forums are only troll answers, so I couldn't look it up there...

Is there some kind of inactivity lock (and when does does it trigger)?
And (more importantly) how do I get my rank back?

Comment: Are you talking about the skill groups? This is the rank you get after winning 10 matches.

Comment: Yes, the skill group rank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CS:GO competitive ranking (which is different from player ranking) is hidden and decays if you are inactive for around a month. This allows players that are still active to continue to essentially take your spot at whatever rank you were; meaning that your rank will go down if enough time passes.

Simply winning one competitive match should give you a rank again.

Comment: 28 days according to the [Wiki](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Competitive)